# Expect is prompting password twice while spawn

Tags: unix, expect

```
spawn ssh -q user@xx.xx.xx.xx
Password:
Password:
```

Expect is expecting null before I sent the password.

Debug info

```
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "yes/no"? no
"Password: "? no
Password:
expect: does "Password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "yes/no"? no
"Password: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Password: "
send: sending "password \r" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*>"? no
```

Comment: The debug output only shows it matching once. Why don't you show your expect script?

Comment: This is my expect script.

for i in xx.xx.xx.xx
do
expect  << EOF
spawn ssh -q user@$i
sleep 2
match_max 600000
expect "yes/no" {
        send "yes\r"
        expect "Password: " { send "password@ \r }
        } "Password: " { send "password@ \r" }
expect "*>" {  send "sudo su - oracle \r" }
expect "Password:" {
        send "password@\r"
        expect "*]" { send " ls -lhrt\r" }
        } "*]" { send " ls -lhrt\r" }
expect "*]" { send  "exit\r" }
expect "*$" { send  "exit\r" }
EOF
done

Comment: Unreadable. Edit your question and add it there.\